# Three digits followed by dash after every two digits regex

Tags: regex, digit

My target is to add three digits followed by a dash on every two digits regex.

Example: Given

> 01234342323

I need to obtain

> 012-34-34-23-23

I am using this regex: `\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`, but it did not work as expected. What should I change on it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern

```
^\d{3}|(?!^)\d{2}(?!$)
```

and replace it with

```
$0-
```

This pattern will match a 3-digit number from the start of the string or a 2-digit-number that's neither at the start (for numbers of only two digits) nor at the end (to avoid trailing `-`). The replacement reinserts the matched string and adds a `-` to it.

See https://regex101.com/r/tLsjCE/1